# Scatter Objects tool distorts scattered objects

Tags: modeling, objects

Scatter objects tool works in a weird way: I created a plane to be a grass blade, applied texture. It worked.

However, when using Scatter Objects tool, the resulting "grass blades" are far from the original shape: they are mostly distorted, bloated, etc.

It works fine with the default cube and the cones, however.
[blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r63R7Avllav6toRQoRuQ-qRbr-hBUwep).

Could anyone tell me how to to this correctly?

[image: scattered grass planes in blender view port]

Comment: The reason "Dear Community" and other such things keep disappearing is because SE's software strips out extraneous text like that (see my edit). Just keep the questions clear and concise, there is no need for greetings or salutations. Welcome to BSE PS please keep your questions to one per post.

Comment: As a guess try to apply scale for the grass plane (Object mode, object selected > Ctrl+A). I didn't use Object Scatter operator, I can't tell if it's part of an addon or a built-in feature